# How to update cart of a guest user after login with Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, authentication, cart

I have a custom e-commerce developed on Zend Framework and am working with the issue of updating the cart of a non-registered user after he logs in. The behaviour should be that the cart, created for the guest user, will be assigned to the authenticated user, with an update of the "cart" table in the DB.
I tried to implement this function in my "loginController.php":

```
function updateCartLogin($userId) {
$this->db->update('cart', array('user_id' => $userId), array('user_id = ?' => getSessionId()));
}
```

This solution doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved the issue:

```
protected function updateCartLogin($userId) {
        $sessionId = $this->getSessionId();
        $this->db->update('cart', array('user_id' => $userId), array('user_id = ?' => $sessionId));
    }
```